# Bootstrap Typeahead send form on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js

I am using typeahead.js autocomplete plugin for suggestions on search box. It works fine, however I would like to perform a search when a user selects option and clicks. How is that possible?

```
<form action="search.php"  method="get">
<input  name="query" class="typeahead" type="text" data-provide="typeahead" autocomplete="off"  required>
<button type ="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

js function

```
         <script>
        $('input.typeahead').typeahead({
        source: function (query, process) {
        $.ajax({
        url: 'data.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: 'query=' + query,
        success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        process(data);
        }
        });
        }
        });
        });
            </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do it

```
   $('input.typeahead').bind("typeahead:selected", function () {
        $("form").submit();
    });
```

Comment: If you set a debugger does it get to the `$("form").submit()` line or does it not not even get into that function?  It's possible that the selector's I used are not 100% correct for your code, but this is the general gist of what you want to do.